# C++ Adding a data member to a struct from another base class

Tags: c++, struct, addition, decorator

Good Day. I am busy coding for a project at University and I would like to know how I can add a data member to a node struct (For a linked list), but the struct has been previously defined. I can't just define it all in the original struct as instructions state otherwise.

Here is my struct, located in ListAsSSL.h file:

```
struct node
{
     node* next;
     Object obj;
};
```

Can I do this in another header file:

```
struct node: node
{
    node* previous;
};
```

Thank you. I did just self-study the Decorator pattern, but it only shows how to do it with classes and not structs.

Thank you for the assistance.
Richard

Comment: Classes and structs are the same thing, but just with different access.

Comment: No, you can't do this. Use inheritance instead.

Comment: no you can't it's redefinition

Comment: You need to implement something around an existing framework (provided by your instructor)? Because if that's the case, I think you are attempting to go about it wrong.

Comment: Given the definition of the original `node` with what looks like a generic "Object" member, it would be very strange to add a `previous` field via inheritance or some other thing.  `next` and `previous` are very symmetric.  Before launching into this, you should probably clarify the instructions with your instructor.  Maybe they meant that you were not to modify `Object`, and that the original `node` is an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot extend a `struct` like that. Create a new `struct` with inheritance instead, like this:

```
struct node
{
     node* next;
     Object obj;
};
```

And in your other file:

```
struct newNode: node
{
    node* previous;
};
```

And in your client code, the code that accesses the struct, you have to use the new struct instead of the old one. Remember, this is what inheritance was built for in many cases: **To add more features to an existing class!**

Comment: @NathanOliver default access is public for structs, no?

Comment: That seems incorrect to me, here is a simplified [example](http://cpp.sh/6zph) @NathanOliver

Comment: @tobi303 Durp.  struct not class.  nvm me

Comment: If the derived type is a `class`, the base is not visible `public`. But if we just stick with `struct`,  then everything is `public` by default. So the answer is valid. (And I'm now going to stop writing `public` on the rare occasions I use inheritance!)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wondered if I could do it like that but I thought it was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new struct? For example:

```
struct nodeV2
{
     Object obj;

     nodeV2* next;
     nodeV2* previous;
};
```

This seems to be the easiest way, to me. This way, you can keep the original struct, while not getting into inheritance.

All the best.

Comment: This violates the principal of the linked list. shouldn't `next` and `previous` be of type `nodeV2`?

Comment: It was a copy-paste mistake from my side. My bad! Thanks for the pointer.I have fixed the issue, following your advise.